# Difficulty understanding Activity Chart

Tags: gantt-chart

I'm reading **Software Engineering** book written by ***Ian Sommerville***. On chapter 23 (Project Scheduling), a hypothetical activity chart is given with tasks, their dependencies and duration.

Following the table of the tasks with their dependencies and duration:

[image]

Now from this table an activity bar chart is created:

[image]

Now I'm having difficulty understanding how Task T1 takes 2 week to finish and T2 takes 3 weeks to finish, although their duration is only 10 and 15 days respectively. Can anybody explain what I'm missing here?

Comment: These are probably 5-day work-weeks (weekends aren't included).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A work week is typically 5 days. Therefore, a 10 day task will take 2 working weeks to finish and a 15 day task will take 3 working weeks to finish.